# character extract from string in swift

Tags: swift, character

I have a task to do something with a chess board. The input gives us a starting position of some chess figure. For example "b4" or "a6" or something like that. How can i decompose the input and make from it two integer numbers, like in C++:

```cpp
string input;
cin>>input

int coord_x = input[0] - 'a';

int coord_y = input[1]
```

I cannot manage to do that in swift. I do something like:

```swift
let input : String=readLine()!
let characters = Array(input)
```

and then try to take the int but it doesnt work, no matter what i try...
and what type is the content of the Array in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the c string representation like this:

```
let string = "a5"
let scalars = string.lowercased().cString(using: .ascii)!

let first = scalars[0]
let second = scalars[1]
```

It could be safer to retrieve the unicodeScalar characters instead:

```
let string = "a5".lowercased()
let characters = Array(string.unicodeScalars)

let first = characters[0].value - UnicodeScalar(unicodeScalarLiteral: "a").value
```

Comment: Int8 is always representable to Int(64), just convert with `Int(first)`.